# Vertical Bars show chemical level android like attached image

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, android-layout

I want to draw same vertical bars to show different levels of different chemicals shown as below image

[image: Vertical chemical level bars]

Can anyone help me to draw the same UI?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need is a vertical SeekBar.Add rotation attribute to normal SeekBar.

```
<SeekBar
    android:id="@+id/seek_bar_1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:rotation="270"/>
```

Then, create a gradient drawable to use it for the SeekBar.

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "utf-8" ?>
<shape
android:shape = "rectangle"
xmlns:android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

<gradient
    android:startColor = "#F40303"
    android:centerColor = "#055798"
    android:endColor = "#00FF0C"
    android:angle = "90"
    android:type = "linear" />
</shape>
```

The, set the progressDrawable to a transparent color. And finally, to prevent users from changing the seekbar knob position, add onTouchListener like this:

```
seekBar.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    return true;
  }
});
```